# Sync wear app on emulator with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, wear-os

I developed a wear app but I can't find a way to deploy the wear app from my phone on the Eclipse emulator (I don't have a real watch). The first question is: is it possible? I checked all:

- phone app has got all permission defined in wear app
- I created the xml and other stuff to do the packaging using the same package name and using the right version and version code
- I put the wear apk in the raw folder to avoid any asset compression problem
- I added to the phone manifest app the information about the wear app
- Compiled with Ant with a custom build.xml with nocompress tag for raw folder

If I export (with my sign) the apks and I install them via adb, the communication works without any problem. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a porting on Android Studio with exactly the same code, the app now works and I can deploy it on the wear emulator. So I think at least with the latest version of Eclipse the packaging of a wear app is completely **broken**. Migrate to **Android Studio**.